# java.util.Collection with the lowest overhead?

Tags: java, collections, overhead

I'm calling a method in another API that accepts a `java.util.Collection` of objects. I've looked at the method and it immediately copies everything in the collection into a new `ArrayList` before performing its task.

This got me wondering: What is the absolute lowest overhead Java Collection that I can use to quickly assemble parameters for this method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That depends on how it copies the elements, but if it creates the `ArrayList`-copy like this

```
new ArrayList<Something>(inputCollection);
```

or if it does

```
someCopy.addAll(inputCollection);
```

then the it will go through the `inputCollection.toArray()` which is probably best implemented by `ArrayList`.

Comment: +1 good answer. Even if .toArray() isn't used, the other option is an iterator of sorts and iterating through an array (the underlying storage in ArrayList) is faster than anything else. So ArrayList is the winner in either case.

Comment: for even better usage of ArrayList, pre-size it when constructing, e.g. `new ArrayList<Foo>(numItems)`.

Comment: @jtahlborn: Can't see how that would help. If you use the constructor-approach it's already handled, and if you use the `addAll` method, ensure capacity is called internally before adding the elements anyway.

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about memory footprint, take a look at [this table](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer/master/ElementCostInDataStructures.txt) in [memory-measurer](https://github.com/DimitrisAndreou/memory-measurer). `Arrays$ArrayList` is missing, but could be a good alternative to `ArrayList` (`Arrays.asList(...)`).

**Update:** I updated the original links to the new location of the project in github. Take into account these metrics are several years old.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your source data.

If your source data is already an array, and the array will not be used by others, the fastest way is to have a thin wrapper:

```
final Object[] source = ...

Collection colllection = new AbstractCollection(){
    public Object[] toArray(){ return source; }
    // other methods don't matter
}
```